# Append zeros to the end of a string

Tags: python

I have two strings I need to make equivalent length:

```
str1 ='AVFGHJK'
str2 ='ADF'
```

I need to append some `0`s to the end of `str2` so it becomes length equivalent to `str1`:

```
str1 ='AVFGHJK'
str2 ='ADF0000'
```

**Output:**

```
str2 ='ADF0000'
```

I have tried to use `zfill`, but it adds zeros to the beginning of the string, not the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.ljust` fo padding char

```
print("ABC".ljust(8, '0'))  # ABC00000
```

And `str.rjust` for leading char

```
print("ABC".rjust(8, '0'))  # 00000ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

String have the `zfill` method that appends zeroes to the LEFT; to add them to the right, you could reverse the string:

```
str2 = str2[::-1].zfill(len(str1))[::-1]

# str2
# Out[14]: 'ADF0000'
```

But indeed, `.rjust` and `.ljust` are more versatile!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it yourself, like that:

```
str1 ='AVFGHJK'
str2 ='ADF'

str2 = str2 +(len(str1) - len(str2))*'0' 

print(str2)
```

**Output:**

`ADF0000`